# PHP Trying to create a method which could add several elements at same time without overwriting

Tags: php, arrays, class, oop, methods

I'm trying to create an array in class, which will contain some users info,the main problem is that every last users name is overwrited by the next one, need to create an array which contain all of them.

```
class Users{
    public $name;
    function add($name){
        $this -> name = $name;
    }
    
}

$users = new Users();
$users->add('Jane');
$users->add('Rick');
$users->add('Niles');

var_dump($users);
```

output should contain each username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want an object to have a list of all users, you must convert the class attribute to  [array type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
you can refactor the code like this

```
class Users{
    public $names = array();
    function add($name){
        $this->names[] = $name;
    }
    
}

$users = new Users();
$users->add('Jane');
$users->add('Rick');
$users->add('Niles');

var_dump($users);
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use an array?

```
class User
{
    protected $name;
    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

$users = [];
$users[] = new User('Jane');
$users[] = new User('Rick');
$users[] = new User('Niles');
```

Comment: And then, if necessary you can create something like a UsersCollection that stores them in an array property, and has methods that know how to operate on the User objects for searching, etc.